# Cascaded dropdown Validation not working with Data Annotated as Required

Tags: asp.net-mvc

### ISSUE / Error  EXPLANATION :

I have a cascaded dropdownlist in which first user will select a 
country and as per his selection cities are getting populated via ajax in which no city is selected initially but just a SELECT option is selected. I have populated my cities at the change event of country dropdown using ajax JSON data from the controller but it seems to me when I call `#CityId.Empty()` its removing all options from the city including the SELECT option which I re inserted through jquery code but that line is getting treated as an Option Item instead of OPTION SELECT due to which validation is assuming it a user selection where as in reality its a message to the user to select any given city. SO please help me out to do that validation working if no city is selected it should not allow me to submit the form.

### Controller CODE :

```
public ActionResult PostAd(ClassifiedItem classifiedItem)
 {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                classifiedItem.PostedDate = DateTime.Now;
                classifiedItem.Obsolete = false;
                classifiedItem.Status = "POSTED";
                db.ClassifiedItems.Add(classifiedItem);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return View("ImageUploader", classifiedItem);
            }
            else
            {
                if (classifiedItem.City_Id == 0 || classifiedItem.City_Id == null)
                {
                    ViewBag.Country_Id = new SelectList(db.Countries, "Id", "Country_Name");
                    ViewBag.City_Id = new SelectList(new List<City>(), "Id", "City_Name",0);
                }
                else
                {
                    SetCascadedCountry(classifiedItem.City_Id);
                }
                Prepare_LOV_Data();
            }
            return View(classifiedItem);
}
```

### View Code :

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Country</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.DropDownList("Country_Id", null, "--Select Country--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })  
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">City</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.DropDownList("City_Id", null,"--Select City--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

### My Script

```
$('document').ready(function () {

    $('#Country_Id').on('change', function (d) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'GetCities',
            method: 'Get',
            cache: false,

            data: { CountryId: $(this).val() },
            success: function (d) {
                $('#City_Id').empty();
                //$('#City_Id').append($('<option/>', { value: 0, text: '--Select City--' }));
                $(d).each(function (index, item) {
                    $('#City_Id').append($('<option/>', { value: item.Id, text: item.City_Name }));
                })

            },
            error: function (d) {
                alert(d);
            }
        })
    });
})
```

Comment: Recommend you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Comment: Thanks Stephen, It seems similar to my requirement I am checking this right now thanks.

Comment: Dear Stephen, I studied the code and its working fine but one thing I havn't got if we are storing coordinates in the viewmodel we don't need to store the id's of Localities and cities because we can always back trace from the coordinates and this is the point where my problem is getting started as If I will not be having fields for city and locality then re-population is a problem so please advise how it should be worked out if in my database I don't have fields for city and locality as I will derive that from the coordinates as suggested by normalization

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean by your last comment. The fiddle is a general example (it was not created specifically for you) - you just need to adapt it for your case.